# Обработка Json Timestamp

Tags: java, json, timestamp

В ответе, полученном с сервера, есть значение типа `Timestamp`, его нужно преобразовать из `Json` в `Timestamp`. Для `int` это можно сделать так:

```
 JSONObject JsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
 int result = userJsonObj.getInt("result");
```

А как это можно сделать для типа `Timestamp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TimeStamp TS = (TimeStamp) JsonObj.get("timestamp");
```